# Styling the headline of an android dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-theme, android-styles

I want to style the header of an Android dialog. Here is what a standard android dialog looks like [image]

what I want is sth like this which I photoshopped (styled background of header and another text color for it). 
[image]

I know that it is possible to pass the theme as a parameter to the Dialog()-Constructor. But I don't know how the xml-style elements would look like.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`setCustomTitle(View)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setCustomTitle%28android.view.View%29) for this. I've never used it, but it should go something like this:

```
TextView title = new TextView(context);
title.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
title.setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
title.setLayoutParams(/* LayoutParams with MATCH_PARENT width and WRAP_CONTENT height */);
title.setPadding(/* Some padding values */);
yourDialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(title);
```

In terms of copying verbatim the layout of the existing Android dialog title, I'm not sure what the parameters of those values are. You may have to mess around and/or Google it to find them. (The font itself is obviously Roboto for 4.0+ and Droid for anything less.)

Comment: Unfortunately this method doesn't exist for a regular Dialog (not an AlarmDialog)

Comment: @Toni4780 Precisely. As [the Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) say: "*The `Dialog` class is the base class for creating dialogs. However, you typically should not instantiate a `Dialog` directly.*"

Answer (score 0):

Its really simple...

All you have to do is to create an XML layout, for the pic you have uploaded and then just simply inflate the Dialog with the XML file you just created .....

I'll just give you a sample code, then you can easily follow

```
private View mView;
private Dialog mDialog;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
```

Now create a function as  :-

```
private void showCustomDialog() {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(
            LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ContextThemeWrapper mTheme = new ContextThemeWrapper(this,
            R.style.YOUR_STYE);

    mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_XML_LAYOUT_FILE, null);
    // mDialog = new Dialog(this,0); // context, theme

    mDialog = new Dialog(mTheme);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDialog.setContentView(this.mView);
    mDialog.show();

    TextViiew someText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
    // do some thing with the text view or any other view 

}
```

Finally make sure you have the style as :-

```
<style name="YOUR_STYLE">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

That's it .... you are done... just call this function where ever you want to show the custom dialog....

Hope the explanation was useful....